# How do I complete the Taking Independence quest?

Tags: fallout-4

Maybe I jumped the gun and now I cannot figure out how to complete the mission "Taking Independence". I discovered the "Quest objectives" (shown below), however I found this out *after* I did everything but talk to Preston Garvey. What I did was just go to the "Castle" and do the items that I have checked with an X below. The map shows "Cleared".

Is the issue that I did the quest out of order? **How do I complete this mission?**

Quest objectives:

- Meet with the Minutemen near the Castle ( I did NOT find them?)
- Plan the attack - X
- Take the courtyard - X
- Destroy the eggs - X
- Kill the Mirelurk Queen - X
- Power up the radio transmitter - X
- Talk to Preston Garvey ( I never saw him at the "Castle" only the Sanctuary)

Comment: In my first attempt right after killing the Queen Preston Garvey was stucked halfway in the ground and refuses to talk. I have powered up the radio, turned it on, but nobody sits there. Luckely, I've make a save right before this mission, so I've loaded a save, kill Queen again and everything was fine. This quest is kinda bugged.

Comment: if you go to the "Castle" there will be a near hideout where the Minuteman will wait for you. That will start the quest and probably reset the area....

Answer (score 2):

There is a small diner near the castle where the Minutemen wait for you. [Fallout wikia describes it](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Taking_Independence#Detailed_walkthrough) like so:

> Garvey is waiting for you in a destroyed Sullivan's west of the Castle with three other Minutemen.

If you never found them, they're probably still there waiting for you.

There are some potentially useful supplies in there as well.